# Starting process from thread with queue as parameter

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to make communication between process started in thread and asyncio event loop. What I want to do is explained here:

[image]

Currently I have problem with pickling queues and I don't really know how to solve it. This is minimal reproducible example of what I'm trying to do:

```
import threading
import asyncio
import queue
import multiprocessing

class Process_Class(object):
    def send_something(self, normal_queue):
        normal_queue.put('something')

class Threading_Class(object):
    def start(self, normal_queue):
        self.normal_queue = normal_queue
        self.processing = Process_Class()
        self.start_process()   

    def start_process(self):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.processing.send_something, args=(self.normal_queue,))
        process.start()

class Async_Class(object):
    async def receive_something(self, normal_queue):
        while True:
            content = normal_queue.get()
            print(content)


thread = Threading_Class()
async_loop = Async_Class()
normal_queue = queue.Queue()

threaded = threading.Thread(target=thread.start, args=(normal_queue,))
threaded.start()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(async_loop.receive_something(normal_queue))
```

and here is error which I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "e:/python_multiprocessing/main.py", line 14, in start
    self.start_process()
  File "e:/python_multiprocessing/main.py", line 18, in start_process
    process.start()
  File "C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 107, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.duplicate(pipe_handle,
  File "C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 79, in duplicate
    return _winapi.DuplicateHandle(
OSError: [WinError 6]
```

I'm using python 3.8.4

Comment: Is using the `janus` module required to reproduce the problem? If not please remove it.

Comment: First of all, any time you send queues through a process, use ``multiprocessing.Queue`` instead.

Comment: @MarcSances Yes, I forgot about that, thanks. But threre is still problem with communication between process and asyncio loop, because this queue must be created in asyncio loop. I'm thinking about one more thread that will be only 'translating' from multiprocessing queue to async queue.